# RuleDelayed (:>) involving Piecewise leads to Piecewise::pairs warning in ReplaceAll (/.)

Tags: replacement, evaluation, pattern-matching, warning-messages, piecewise

When I write a replacement rule like this:

```
Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}}] /. Piecewise[a_, b___] :> Piecewise[a, b]
```

It works fine, but I get the unexpected warning `Piecewise::pairs`, i.e. "The first argument a_ of Piecewise is not a list of pairs". Is this a bug?

Comment: This is in `13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)`

Comment: Actually `ReplaceAll` isn't relevant here. Executing `Piecewise[a_, b___] :> Piecewise[a, b]` is enough to reproduce the warning.

Comment: I know, I was just confused because I somehow thought that within the rule the expression would _not_ be evaluated.

Comment: `RuleDelayed` only owns `HoldRest` attribute, that's the reason it doesn't hold the first argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While creating the delayed rule Mathematica evaluates the left hand side of the rule by default. Evaluating `Piecewise[a_, b___]` returns the error message, but stays unevaluated. You can silence the error by wrapping it in `Quiet`, but probably the most orthodox method is to wrap it on `HoldPattern` which specifically prevents this evaluation:

```
Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}}] /. 
 HoldPattern[Piecewise[a_, b___]] :> Piecewise[a, b]
```